# Searching for substrings in file.readlines() in python

Tags: c#, python, string, search

Just starting with python, so excuse me if I sound utterly thick.

assuming the following input:
my_file content:

> we love unicorns
>   we love beer
>   we love free (an in free beer)

I have expected the following to return true:

```
# my_file = some path to valid file
with open(my_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if 'beer' in lines:
        print("found beer") # this does not happen
```

or am I just too used to c#'s way, after which I'll have all the matching lines:

```
// assuming I've done a similar lines = open and read from file
var v = from line in lines
        where line.Contains("beer")
        select line;
```

What would be the pythonian equivalent to fetching those lines that hold `beer` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, you need to check for the substring in each line, not in the list of lines.

```
with open(my_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'beer' in line:
            print("found beer")
```

As an example,

```
lines = ['this is a line', 'this is a second line', 'this one has beer']
```

This first case is basically what you are trying to do

```
>>> 'beer' in lines
False
```

This is what the code I showed above would do

```
>>> for line in lines:
        print('beer' in line)

False
False
True
```

Comment: yep, I've figured out that I need the second loop inside... since `readlines()` basically returns the lines with the `\n` appended ... feels weird that I can't use that ... Wondered if `with open(my_file).readlines() as lines:` would work ...but it doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
with open(my_file) as f:
    data = f.read()  # reads everything to a string
    if 'beer' in data:
        print("found beer")
```

OR more efficiently:

```
with open(my_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'beer' in line:
            print("found beer")
```

Comment: The first option is not what i want. I'm actually hunting for specific lines . I like the second though ... wasn't aware that I can skip the `readlines()` altogether ...